# bxslider-4- doesn't work in Safari

Tags: jquery-plugins, bxslider

I use bxslider-4 plugin (The fully-loaded, responsive jQuery content slider) for creating picture slider. For some reason it doesn't work in Safari. Is anyone familiar with this issue?

```
<div class="mini-resume-content">


                <p><span class="text-default">DHJKDFSHJK HDJKSHFKD
DKSFL;K;
,sl;ajd;asj; dfnsdlk</span></p>





    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if('true'){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/threebaysover/profile/accomodationOverview",
        type:"post",
        data: {id:'10'},
        success:function(data){
            $('#accomendation').html(data);
        }

    });
    }
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});


        var mme = $("#mypanel");
        mme.mmenu({
            classes: "mm-white"}).on('click', '.mm-subclose', function () {
            $("#mypanel").trigger('close.mm');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Could you clarify in what way?

Comment: the pictures are not displayed in a slide

Comment: Using safari for mac OS X the slider works fine on their website and on a site I designed (see https://vivid-hypnotherapy.co.uk). Do these both work on yours?

Comment: @cwyatt1- in your  site it works. But in my case it doesn't (noticed that i'm using it for Safari in mobile).

Comment: @cwyatt1- I have noticed that it doesn't recognise property of the css with * like (*zoom: 1;)

Comment: Could it be the spelling of accommodation in the id that is causing it?

Comment: @cwyatt1- the problem in the Safari that in the ajax call there is nothing in bxslider